# Is there a special name for matrices A and C if ABC=B

Tags: matrices, terminology

I have the following three matrices that satisfy:

$$A\cdot B\cdot C=B$$

Is there a special term to describe the matrices A and C? Or what is the relationship between $A$ and $C$?

I have realized that $A$ and $C$ are in general not inverse matrices of each other, since in general:

$$AB=BC^{-1}\ne C^{-1}B$$

I have also been able to deduce that:

$$B=A^{-1}BC^{-1}$$

by multiplying $A^{-1}$ on the left and $C^{-1}$ on the right on both sides.

However, this doesn't seem to imply anything special about $A$ and $C$. To make it clear, I am asking if there is any special connection between $A$ and $C$, and/or if there is a special term for it.

**Note**: For my application, all matrices are $4\times4$ rigid transformation matrices, so they are all invertible, but I am not sure if this is an important requirement or not.

Comment: well, if $A,B$ and $C$ are invertible, then we can say that $A^{-1}$ and $C$ are [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) (and $B$ is their similarity transformation), indeed $ABC=B$ implies that $A^{-1}=BCB^{-1}$. I'm not sure if this is what you want though.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't come across rearranging the equation that way... But this is interesting enough! I just felt this equation is quite beautiful and I feel there has to be something special about $A$ and $C$, but I did not manage to figure it out myself.

Comment: Invertibility of $B$ (which implies invertibility of $A$ and $C$) is indeed an important requirement.  Otherwise you could have $B = 0$ and $A$ and $C$ could be any matrices of the right dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $A,B$ are invertible, then the relation $ABC=B$ implies that $A^{-1}$ and $C$ are [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) matrices. Indeed, we have 
$$ C = (AB)^{-1}B = B^{-1}A^{-1}B$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $A=BC^{-1}B^{-1}$, $A$ is similar to $C^{-1}$.